# Check whether any html tags or javascript code entered in textfield

Tags: html, validation, textfield

Now I have a textfiled. I want user can not enter html tag or javascript code in this textfield.

I tried to use `getElementsByTagName` however it is only prevent entel html tag. I also prevent user input javascript code in textfield.

How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
onkeyup="javascript:this.value=this.value.replace(/[<,>]/g,'');"
```

Comment: I want user still can input < symbol. Any other solution?

Comment: If want to allow only < symbol then you have to allow html tag from frontend.  You can  strip_tags() (php) to remove html tags